# How to bring to attention spiteful down-voting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I am almost convinced that there is an experienced user on the site, who keeps down-voting my posts. The experienced user seems to know the tricks of the trade, i.e., this user is aware that serial down-voting will be easily noticed and will be reversed by the system. Hence, this user seems to down-vote my posts once/twice a day. Is there a way to figure out the culprit and reverse the down-votes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. As far as I can tell, no user has ever given you 5 or more downvotes (not just within a period of time but overall).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can alert the moderators without posting on meta (or) leaving a comment on some question? Is there a more direct way to contact the moderators through the website?

Comment: @user17762: You can always use free-form flags on your own question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But that seems to be a roundabout way. Flagging a random question to raise concern about some other issue (which has nothing to do with the question) seems to be a wrong way to catch moderator attention. Shouldn't there be a more direct way to contact the moderators?

Comment: @user17762: I agree that a simpler "contact moderators" form would have been wonderful, but to my knowledge there is no such form. There is a system to reply to a moderator notice, but you can only reply and only once for every notice. You can use the flag system to request to be contacted by email, or otherwise. Also, flag a post that has been affected (in this case downvoted), this wouldn't be random at all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. Yes, in the case of down-voting, it seems to make sense to flag the post under suspicion. Wish there was a better way to grab moderator's attention for other things, in general.

Comment: @user17762: it's not really "nothing to do with the question" if you're flagging a question that was down-voted. There's also a "contact us" link at the bottom of every page that goes straight to the SE admin mailbox.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, as I mentioned to Asaf, in the case of down-voting, it seems to make sense to flag the post under suspicion. Thanks for the "contact us". Do the moderators  of the specific site also get notified when a message is sent through "contact us"?

Comment: @user17762: no, not unless we need to let them know for some reason. Voting anomalies are pretty easy to check for, so unless something really twisted is going on we'll just let you know. Normally, you don't want to flag *or* contact us unless you've seen something pretty blatant and given the system at least 24-hours to automatically handle it.